# Using $watch, table div dissapear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm using `isteven-multi-select` directive for multi-select dropdown. I'm giving it `thingsList` and it creates `checkedList` while I choose things.

So at first I used button to confirm selection and `ng-click` triggered `postFunction` with `checkedList`. And it worked fine.

But then I decided to add a watcher so I wouldn't need to press the button. As I can see at debug mode it's working (list is updates correctly), but there is a problem. I'm showing updated list at the page with `datatables`. But somehow, after choosing anything at dropdown ($watch event) `<div> with table` is dissapearing. And it'not ng-show or something it dissapears from DOM itself.

I have no idea why.

```
this.postThings = function (checkedList) {
        $http.post("/list/" JSON.stringify(checkedList)).then(
            function success(response) {
                $scope.thingsList.splice(0);   
                Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.thingsList, response.data);
            },
            function error(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.notify({message: data.data.message}, {type: 'danger'});
            }
        );
    };


$scope.$watch(function (scope) {
            return scope.checkedList
        },
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if ($scope.checkedList.length == 0) {
                vm.bindBack();
            } else {
                vm.bindNew($scope.checkedList);
            }
        });
```

directive:

```
<isteven-multi-select input-model="thingsList"
                          output-model="checkedList"
                          button button-label="icon name"
                          item-label="icon name maker"
                          tick-property="check">
</isteven-multi-select>
```

HTML that dissapears:

```
        ...
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h3>Things:/h3>
            <table datatable="ng" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="thing in thingsList">
                    <td>{{thing .id}}</td>
                    <td><a ui-sref="thing Info({thing Id: thing .id})">{{thing .name}}</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        ...
```

Comment: We have no idea what the functions used inside the watch do. Provide all relevant code. A plunker demo would really help. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl, basically both `bindNew` and `bindBack` is the same as `postThings`. It sends post request and get back the data.

Comment: Well without a demo that reproduces problem not sure anyone can help

Comment: @charlietfl I've never been good with plnkr. It doesn't work at all over there. https://plnkr.co/edit/OCkpI3i2D9SNh5cnOjCC?p=preview

Comment: One issue is you are mixing controllerAs and $scope methodology. Also `datatable="ng"` ... no such scope variable

Comment: @charlietfl but it works for me. ng is datatable's variable, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. There's known bug in `angular-datatables`, where multiple rerenderings somehow erase < table > from the DOM.
https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/729

> So the idea is to stop constant rerendering, not trigger the bug.

For me solution was, to add checking if newValue has different length then oldValue. Now there's no constant rerender and it works fine.

```
$scope.$watch(function (scope) {
        return scope.checkedList
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue.length != oldValue.length) {
        if ($scope.checkedList.length == 0) {
            vm.bindBack();
        } else {
            vm.bindNew($scope.checkedList);
        }
     }
    });
```